# Drag & Drop Delphi XE5

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, delphi-xe5

I use Delphi XE5 and have to realize the possibility for the user to drag different files (docx, xlsx, pictures (jpeg, gif, ...), E-Mails, ... into a component. The component should show the filename or the header of the E-Mail.
Than i want to save this file into a Blob-field in the SQL-Server Database.

Can anyone tell me whats the best possibility if possible with a short example.
Can i realize this with the standard delphi components or is it necessary to install special components.

Answer (score 2):

Your component needs to be derived from `TWinControl` (`TCustomControl`, etc) so it has its own `HWND` to drag things onto.  Then:

1. if you just want to capture dragged filenames, your component can process the [`WM_DROPFILES`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774303.aspx) window message.  This is a legacy message, but it still works.  However, it only works when dragging physical files from the file system onto your window.  For more advanced scenarios (dragging virtual data, dragging data from other apps, etc), you need to...
2. a. implement the [`IDropTarget`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679679.aspx) interface instead.  Write an object that implements `IDropTarget`, or use a third-party implementation such as from [Ander's Melander's Drag&Drop suite](http://melander.dk/delphi/dragdrop/).

   b. register that object for your component's `HWND` using [`RegisterDragDrop()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678405.aspx) after it has been created (the best place to do that in in your component's overridden `CreateWnd()` method), and unregister the object using [`RevokeDragDrop()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692643.aspx) when the `HWND` is being destroyed (such as in the overridden `DestroyWnd()` method).

   c. when the user drags something onto your component's window, your [`IDropTarget.DragEnter()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680106.aspx) implementation will be called. Examine the provided [`IDataObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688421.aspx) to see if it holds a data format + transport scheme that you support (there can be multiple combinations at one time).  Each piece of data will be identified by a unique clipboard format identifier, and a [`TYMED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691227.aspx) value indicating how the data is transferred.  Some clipboard formats are pre-defined (see [Shell Clipboard Formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776902.aspx)), and some can be registered dynamically at runtime (see [`RegisterClipboardformat()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649049.aspx)).  If you find a combination that you support, return `DROPEFFECT_COPY` to accept the drag, otherwise return `DROPEFFECT_NONE` to reject the drag.

   d. if the user drops something onto your component's window (if accepted by `DragEnter()`), your [`IDropTarget.Drop()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687242.aspx) implementation will be called. Extract the data from the provided `IDataObject` and use it as needed.  When dropping physical files, you will receive their paths+names and/or their [`ITEMIDLIST`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773321.aspx) identifiers, then you can open and read the files as needed.  When dropping virtual data/files, you will get the actual data instead (which is usually transferred as a block of memory in an `HGLOBAL` that you can access using [`GlobalLock()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366584.aspx), or as an [`IStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380034.aspx) interface, but there are other possibilities available).

See MSDN for more details:

[Transferring Shell Objects with Drag-and-Drop and the Clipboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776905.aspx)

[Shell Data Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776903.aspx)

[Handling Shell Data Transfer Scenarios](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776904.aspx)