# Detect Dragging File event before Dropped on Form

Tags: delphi, pascal

I'm trying to create an application for Windows.
In my application, when dragging items File from Windows Explorer to FormOne and then FormOne will call FormSecond show and Drop Items on FormSecond.
My proplem is: I wrote code for FormSecond to handle received Files is Fine. But on FormOne I don't know how to catch dragging event mouse on FormOne to show FormSecond.

Everybody can help me, please!!!
Sorry, my English is not good!

Comment: Looks too complex. Perhaps it is simpler to receive files in FormOne (create list of files), then show second from and send file list to it?

Comment: "_I writed code for FormSecond to handle received Files_" - then add that code to your question.

Comment: Check [The Drag and Drop Component Suite for Delphi](http://melander.dk/delphi/dragdrop/) and [How to catch files dragged and dropped on an application from Explorer](https://delphidabbler.com/articles/article-11)

Comment: Related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35188378/

Answer (score 2):

When the user drags files from Windows Explorer onto a `TForm`, there are two different ways to handle the drop:

1. Have the Form either:

   - override the virtual [`CreateWnd()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.CreateWnd) method to call [`DragAcceptFiles()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-dragacceptfiles), or:
   - override the virtual [`CreateParams()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.CreateParams) method to enable the `WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES` window style.

   And then have the Form catch the [`WM_DROPFILES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/wm-dropfiles) window message. The message's `wParam` value is an `HDROP` handle that you can pass to the [`DragQueryFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Shellapi/nf-shellapi-dragqueryfilew), [`DragQueryPoint()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Shellapi/nf-shellapi-dragquerypoint), and [`DragFinish()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Shellapi/nf-shellapi-dragfinish) APIs.
2. Write a class that implements the [`IDropTarget`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleidl/nn-oleidl-idroptarget) interface, implementing the various `Drag(Enter|Over|Leave)()` and `Drop()` methods to query the file information from the provided [`IDataObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-idataobject). Then have the Form pass an instance of that class to [`RegisterDragDrop()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ole2/nf-ole2-registerdragdrop). See [Transferring Shell Objects with Drag-and-Drop and the Clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/dragdrop) for more details.

Comment: I have solved the problem. Thank you so much everyone!
I followed this guide: https://delphidabbler.com/articles/article-24